# Can a child thread kill a parent thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

Hi I have a simple question:

I have a parent thread that spawns multiple threads (child threads). If a method in the child thread exit(1), will the parent thread and other child threads also exit?

Comment: What keeps you from simply trying it out or reading the documentation?

Comment: Answering your question, no, who creates thread gain control over them (not vice versa); however you can force this **safe** behaviour by changing a value, an attribute, something in parent thread, like a boolean variable `should_end` making it `True`

Answer (score 1):

`sys.exit()` will close just the thread, `os._exit()` will kill the entire program:

**using `sys.exit()`:**

```py
import sys, time
from threading import Thread


def testexit():
    print("in thread")
    time.sleep(5)
    sys.exit()
    print("after thread exit")  # will never print...


t = Thread(target=testexit)
t.start()
t.join()
print("in main, after thread exit")  # this will print...
```

Output:

```
in thread
in main, after thread exit
```

**using `os._exit()`:**

```py
import sys, time
from threading import Thread
import os


def testexit():
    print("in thread")
    time.sleep(5)
    os._exit(1)
    print("after thread exit")  # will never print...


t = Thread(target=testexit)
t.start()
t.join()
print("in main, after thread exit")  # this will also not print...
```

Output:

```
in thread
```

Comment: this only answers half my question so it only gets a upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small test to find out the full answer to my own question:

```
import sys
import threading

import os

import time


class ThreadManager(object):
    default_threads = 8

    def __init__(self, thread_count=default_threads):
        self.threads = []
        self.thread_count = thread_count
        self.run_thread = None

    def add(self, thread):
        if not isinstance(thread, threading.Thread):
            sys.exit("Error: thread value must be of type: Thread")

        thread.ran = False
        self.threads.append(thread)

    def start(self):
        if not self.run_thread:
            print("starting run thread")
            self.run_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run)
            self.run_thread.start()

        else:
            print("run thread already active")

    def run(self):
        unran_threads = [t for t in self.threads if not t.ran]
        while unran_threads:
            running_threads = [t for t in self.threads if t.isAlive()]
            while len(running_threads) < self.thread_count and unran_threads:
                thread = unran_threads.pop()
                print("starting thread: %s", thread.name)
                thread.start()
                thread.ran = True
                running_threads.append(thread)

            unran_threads = [t for t in self.threads if not t.ran]

        for thread in self.threads:
            thread.join()

        print("run thread completed")
        self.run_thread = None


def good_method():
    try:
        time.sleep(5)
        print(1/2)
    except ZeroDivisionError as zde:
        print(zde)
        exit(1)


def bad_method():
    try:
        print(1/0)
    except ZeroDivisionError as zde:
        print(zde)
        # os._exit(1)
        exit()


def main():
    tm = ThreadManager(4)
    tm.add(threading.Thread(target=bad_method))
    tm.add(threading.Thread(target=good_method))
    tm.add(threading.Thread(target=good_method))
    tm.add(threading.Thread(target=good_method))

    print('Start all threads')
    tm.run()
    print('Finish all threads')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It seems that if i perform a simple exit() the output is as follows:

```
Start all threads
starting thread: %s Thread-4
starting thread: %s Thread-3
starting thread: %s Thread-2
starting thread: %s Thread-1
division by zero
0.5
0.5
0.5
run thread completed
Finish all threads
```

Where else, if i use osi._exit(1), the output is as follows:

```
Start all threads
starting thread: %s Thread-4
starting thread: %s Thread-3
starting thread: %s Thread-2
starting thread: %s Thread-1
division by zero
```

Conclusion: calling a simple exit() will not kill the parent nor the same level child threads. Calling osi._exit(1) will kill everyone

Thanks to Adam.Er8 for giving me an idea how to make my own test